# How to hide items in JCombobox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have an application that uses a Swing - JCombobox.

I prepared standard DefaultComboBoxModel and I added all items to model, but I would like hide from users some items when he wants select them from PopupMenu.

I don't want to change the model(remove items).

Comment: Do I get this right - you want to have some items in a comboBox, which are hidden ? If so please explain the popup selection concept, I feel a bit lost

Comment: You are complicating things. On your popupMenu action, you should rebuild your list accordingly. Does the value of your PopUp have an effect on the values to hide/show?

Answer (score 2):

You could keep the items in a separate master list and dynamically create the filtered Model based on the user action.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add/remove items in the model.

If you don't want that approach, you can have different models with different items and set them appropriately to the JComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right the following article may be of use - instead of removing the item, you can disable it based on some condition:

[article](http://www.algosome.com/articles/enable-disable-jcombobox.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may Create custom combobox model.

Answer (score 0):

Cache your objects in a list and then use it to build your combo...

```
List objects<ComboItem> = new ArrayList<ComboItem>;

objects.add(1,"Visible String 1", "Value 1");
objects.add(1,"Visible String 2", "Value 2");
objects.add(2,"Visible String 3", "Value 3");
...

class ComboItem
{
    private int group;
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public ComboItem(int group, String key, String value)
    {
        this.group = group; 
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public int getGroup()
    {
        return group;
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

...
```

from here you add item that only from the group you need.. upon user selection.

iterate through you list and add the ones you want according to its group for example.

```
for (String temp : objects) {
    if (temp.getGroup == 1) {
      comboBox.add(temp.key.temp.value);
    }
}
```